# tablesorter Get table header name from currentSortedby = sorter.target.config.sortList;

Tags: html-table, tablesorter

Is there anyone who can get table header name from  `currentSortedby = sorter.target.config.sortList;`?

let's say the table has Column1 and Column2, and I have value `currentSortedby [[1,0]]`. how do I get the name of column header name Column2?

I want information display on the page: Column2 Desc  , Column1 Asc ,etc.

Comment: Bypass this question, I have created fiddle to solve this, tricky thing :) please see this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1357/

Answer (score 1):

Bypass this question, I have created fiddle to solved this, tricky thing :) please see this solution: jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1357